# Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'ProductsComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular

Im trying to access the main route on my server at

> http://localhost:4200

The full error message is:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected directive 'ProductsComponent' imported by
>   the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
>       at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690)
>       at compiler.es5.js:15382
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   (compiler.es5.js:15365)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.es5.js:26795)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.*compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.es5.js:26768)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
>   (compiler.es5.js:26697)
>       at PlatformRef*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.*bootstrapModuleWithZone
>   (core.es5.js:4536)
>       at PlatformRef*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule
>   (core.es5.js:4522)
>       at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)

Other router endpoints such as

> http://localhost:4200/cart

also give the same error

Here is my main file

> app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
    import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';
    import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
    import { AppRoutingModule, routingComponents } from './app.routes';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductsComponent,
        CartComponent,
        MenuComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        routingComponents
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent,routingComponents]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my rooting file

> app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'Products' },
   { path: 'Products', component: ProductsComponent },
   { path: 'Menu', component: MenuComponent },
   { path: 'Cart', component: CartComponent },
 ];

 @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class AppRoutingModule { }

 export const routingComponents = [ProductsComponent, MenuComponent, CartComponent];
```

The app seems to be starting fine on my local development.

Answer (score 8):

You can [import only classes adorned by `@NgModule` decorator](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-import). So move `routingComponent` from `imports` to `declarations`:

```typescript
 @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      ProductsComponent,
      CartComponent,
      MenuComponent,
      routingComponents // add here
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule,
      AppRoutingModule
    ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `routingComponents`. I don't see that that is doing anything and may be causing this problem.